# Why does modifying one session variable also modify a different session variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a weird problem. One of my variables is changed via this function (code below). I don't know how it is possible. I want to change `Session["p_skok"]`, but in some way, variable `Session["z_skok"]` is also changing.

```
    protected void oblicz_parametry()
    {
        List<string> lista_odnosnik_wartosc = (List<string>)Session["p_wartosc"];
        List<Type> lista_odnosnik_typ = (List<Type>)Session["p_typ"];
        List<bool> lista_odnosnik_inkrementacja = (List<bool>)Session["p_inkrementacja"];
        List<int> lista_odnosnik_nr = (List<int>)Session["p_nr"];
        List<int> lista_odnosnik_skok = (List<int>)Session["p_skok"];

        List<int> lista_odnosnik_skok_pomocnicza = (List<int>)Session["z_skok"];
        if (Session["iteracja"] != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lista_odnosnik_inkrementacja.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (lista_odnosnik_skok[i] == 0 && lista_odnosnik_inkrementacja[i] == true)
                {
                    int zwieksz = lista_odnosnik_nr[i];
                    //if (lista_odnosnik_typ[i].ToString() == "int")
                    //{
                        int zm_pomocnicza = Convert.ToInt32(lista_odnosnik_wartosc[i]) + lista_odnosnik_nr[i];
                        lista_odnosnik_wartosc[i] = zm_pomocnicza.ToString();
                    //}
                    lista_odnosnik_skok[i] = lista_odnosnik_skok_pomocnicza[i] + 1;
                }
                lista_odnosnik_skok[i]--;
            }
            Session["p_wartosc"] = lista_odnosnik_wartosc;
            Session["p_skok"] = lista_odnosnik_skok;

        }
        else
        {
            Session["iteracja"] = 1;
            Session["p_wartosc"] = Session["z_wartosc"];
            Session["p_inkrementacja"] = Session["z_inkrementacja"];
            Session["p_nr"] = Session["z_nr"];
            Session["p_skok"] = Session["z_skok"];

            oblicz_parametry();

        }
    }
```

I did some debugging and found out that decreasing happens because of `lista_odnosnik_skok[i]--;` part of the code. Do you know what might be happening?

Comment: Because that's how the code was written?  What are you expecting that line to do?  It decrements the `i`th value in the list.

Comment: In which place? I assign value of this session variable to another variable (from Session["z_skok"] to Session["p_skok], and then never use the first one.

Comment: ADyson yeah, but I decrease value of lista_odnosnik_skok[i], then assign it to Session["p_skok"]. This is ok, but why Session["z_skok"] changes too?

Comment: @Caius Jard Exacly - I change lista_odnosnik_skoki[i] and see changes in lista_odnosnik_skok_pomocnicza[i]

Comment: If this runs a second time, they would both point to the same instance of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a combination of two things. In the `else` clause you have this:

```
Session["p_skok"] = Session["z_skok"];
```

Once you do that, those two variables refer to the same list. Now whatever you do to one list, you're doing to the other, because they're the same list.

Then you're setting `Session["iteracja"] = 1;`, which means next time the condition `if (Session["iteracja"] != null)` will be true.

Within that condition you're making changes to `lista_odnosnik_skok`, which is `Session["p_skok"]` which is the same list as `Session["z_skok"];`.

---

To solve it, don't set the one session variable equal to the other. You could do this:

```
var existingList = (List<int>)Session["z_skok"];
Session["p_skok"] = new List<int>(existingList);
```

Now you've created a new list that contains the same elements as the original list. They're two distinct lists, so modifying one doesn't modify the other.

It's worth noting that this works because `int` is a value type, not a reference type, so when you add the values from one list to the other list you're creating new values. You can modify the values in one list without modifying the others.

If the items in the list were reference types you'd still have a similar problem. You'd have two lists (good) but they would both contain references to the same objects (probably bad). You'd be able to add or delete on one list without modifying the other list, but modifying the item in the list would modify the item in the other list, because they're both the same item.

But again, that's just for explanation. The list contains `int` so in this case it's not a problem.

---

It might also be easier to follow if you read everything you need out of `Session` into variables at the beginning, and then save everything back to `Session` at the end. That way you're not trying to keep track of both local variables and session variables at the same time. It's confusing, which means it's easier to make mistakes.

You might even find it helpful to define a new class that contains all of these lists. Retrieve that one object from session (if it's null create new one), and when you're done working with it, save the whole object. It's the same as what you're doing, but now you're only dealing with one session variable instead of five, and it's even easier to keep track of.

Comment: Yeah, that helped. Thanks for the help and for the explanation - I know why it was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

At some point in the lifecycle of your program you set these two session variables equivalent:

```
Session["p_skok"] = Session["z_skok"];
```

This line of code is in the `else` block. The session will survive for a long time, perhaps hours:

---

[image]

---

After this line of code has run they will both refer to the same list object in memory and any changes inflicted on the contents of either `Session["p_skok"]` or `lista_odnosnik_skok`, or `Session["z_skok"];` or `lista_odnosnik_skok_pomocnicza` will all have the same effect because they're all references to the same `List<int>`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, but I checked the code and I don't have a line like that. I checked also for non-direct reference (e.g. Session -> var -> var -> var -> Session) and found nothing.

Comment: I added a screenshot of your code from your post, with the line you didn't think exist, in a yellow highlight...

Comment: I don't know if I understand it correctly. So, that means that in this example Session["p_skok"] = Session["z_skok"] is the same as Session["z_skok"] = Session["p_skok"]? Because they both point to the same list? I mean this else happens only once, to assign values to Session[p_...] so I don't have to work on original Session variables. How to resolve it?

Comment: Should I create a local variable and somehow transfer this list to it? And then point session to it?

Comment: That would still be assigning a reference to another session variable.